Magento 2.4.6-P5 after upgrade new products not visible
After upgrading to magento 2.4.6-P5 we added some new products but those are not visible in search or on category page. Indexing done, cache is clean.
In the error log is this error:
main.CRITICAL: TypeError:

Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Storage\DynamicStorage::getBaseName():
Return value must be of type string, null returned in
/var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Storage/DynamicStorage.php:260

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

I found the problem finally.
We import a lot of products with a csv-file. Most of them are clothes with different colors and sizes. Magento makes the URL-key.
We make the configurable 'parent' record ourselves. In the past there was no problem, sometimes we had to change the configurable record a bit to be accepted.
After the upgrade every product is accepted, also the configurable with an identical url-key, but the new products are not showing. Change the url-key in a unique url-key and it is showing. Not a very nice change because the url-keys from child products are not visible in the shop.
It is a lot more work to import productrecords now because we have to edit every record.

@Cisca
Hey, refer the below given points,

Reindex and Clear Cache
Ensure that all products and categories have non-null URL keys
bin/magento catalog:product:reindex

Thank You!

After the Magento upgrade, we faced customization issues. To fix this, we need to make sure type cast the function argument and return type correctly.
Wherever it is expected to return or accept a string, make sure to add a condition like the one below.
$string ?? ""

If you have any specific instance, please share it.
